# Is there any reason to have nested calls to $ (jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was poking around the source code of a website when I came across some code like this:

```
$($('#newForm_step1')).hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 0);
```

and this:

```
$($($('.breadcrumbs')[0]).children().last()).html("...");
```

I've never seen the `$` (`jQuery`) function used this way, and I was wondering if there'd be any practical reason to do something like this? To the best of my knowledge, wrapping a jQuery object with a call to `$` simply returns a jQuery object for the same selector, and methods on jQuery objects return `this`, so I don't see why one would need nested calls to `$`.

Comment: It can make sense for a function to wrap one of its arguments in `$()` to allow for values that might sometimes be jQuery objects and other times be a selector or DOM element. But nesting around a hard-coded selector makes no sense.

Comment: There's no obvious reason in the first example. The second example could be avoided by using `.first()` instead of `[0]`

Comment: It can also be used to make a clone of the jQuery object, so perhaps if there was a stateful object such as one that hadn't been added to the DOM yet, then it would make a difference.

Comment: @Phil - even allowing for the `[0]` there is still an extra bonus level of nesting in that example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no reason to do this.

In the first example, `$($(...))` is redundant. There is absolutely no effect in immediately wrapping a jQuery object in another jQuery object.

The line should read

```
$('#newForm_step1').hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 0);
```

In the second example, `$(...)[0]` returns a raw DOM element, so it's wrapped again before having jQuery's `.children().last()` invoked on it. The result of that is already a jQuery object, so there is no need to re-wrap it, and the "unwrapping" could have been avoided by calling `.first()` instead of `[0]`.

The line should read

```
$('.breadcrumbs').first().children().last().html("...");
```

Comment: Thanks! It is as I had thought. The website it's from is Coursera, which is... interesting to say the least lol.

Answer (score 0):

There's no necessary to wrap jQuery object with jQuery. That will just result the same but over-coding and redundant.

But when you have DOM Object then you need to wrap with jQuery so that it will be jQuery object.

Taking your example:

```
$('.breadcrumbs')[0];//[0] converts to JavaScript Object
```

Now, if you want to work with jQuery again, you may then wrap with jQuery:

```
$($('.breadcrumbs')[0]);//is now a jQuery Object
```

But with this example is unnecessary because you can do just like this:

```
$('.breadcrumbs:eq(0)');//selects first .breadcrumbs element
```

However, if you have some DOM Object rather than jQuery object then you need jQuery wrapper to work with jQuery methods.

---

You must remember this:

JavaScript Object needs JavaScript methods to be chained:

```
javascriptObject.javascriptMethods
```

Ex-

```
$('.breadcrumbs')[0].addEventListener();//javascript addEventListener method
```

jQuery Object needs jQuery methods to be chained:

```
jQueryObject.jQueryMethods
```

Ex-

```
$('.breadcrumbs').on();//jQuery on method
```

Comment: A jQuery object is a JavaScript object too. You might want to clarify that first code comment

Comment: right -- plain old javascript objects have only POJO methods, while jQuery objects have jQuery methods in addition to all the POJO ones (unless overridden)